# Swift opening a new view controller programmatically

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm working on an workout app. I finished everything now I'm stuck at the details.
So when my workout finishes it needs to open a new view controller which will tell the user that he finished the workout.
I have tried to do it with this code:

```
var storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    //var vc: UINavigationController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("newViewController") as! UINavigationController

    var vc: EndOfWorkout = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("newView") as! EndOfWorkout

    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But it opens sometimes and sometimes not. Also when it opens it closes after a short period of time.
I need also at the end that the user is able to go back to the main menu but none of the examples that I tried are working.

Comment: Are you calling dismissViewController immediately before or after this presentation

Comment: What's calling this code? Is it always being called from the main thread? And are there any warnings in the output window?

Comment: I solved it in a different way

Comment: Is this code inside a closure, executed after some network task or background processing? If yes, I'd ensure that it is run in the main thread

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your vc variable might be destroyed by ARC, try setting this instance in a property of your controller.

Something like that :

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController{

     private var vc: EndOfWorkout?

     override func viewDidLoad() {
     ...
         vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("newView") as! EndOfWorkout
     }

}
```